# How to debug what causes Windows 11 context menu to freeze whole explorer and remove it from the list?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, freeze, context-menu

When I press right mouse button on text, text-like file, zip archives on my Windows 11 machine - file explorer freezes, then when I force close it - whole explorer restarts.

How can I debug what causes this behaviour? I recently installed Visual Studio Code and allowed "Open with Code" in context menu but I don't know if this is what causes the problem.

Comment: Revert any additional context menu additions. Then one by one add them back. There is a hard limit on the number of context menu options

Comment: How can I revert them? Is there like a tool to check date when they were added and remove them? @Ramhound

Comment: You could look into "Ultimate Windows Context Menu Customizer" or look at editing the  Windows registry for the context menu entries.

Comment: It is almost 100% caused by a shell extension you have installed.  [This tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) (ShellExView) will let you disable (and examine) what is happening on the right click. [AutoRuns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) is also good for this.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting my Windows 11 machine problem disappeared.

After I switched from Macbook to Windows 11 laptop I was too accustomed to using machine without restarting once in a while so it was a huge surprise for me (after 2 weeks of agony of not being able to use context menu) that windows 11 restart resolved everything.